# Using the graph "Square root of 7,interval and the line where x is twice y "

Tags: roots, graphing-functions

Given below is the graph of the function $ y  =  x^2  − 4x − 3$, Using the Graph
[image]
  (iii) write down the interval of values of $x$ for which the function is increasing in the interval     $−6 < y < 0$.

(iv) find the roots of the equation $x^2  −  4x  − 3  =  0$ and hence obtain the value of $\sqrt{7}$ to the     nearest first decimal place.

(v) by drawing a suitable straight line, write down the coordinates of a point on the graph of     which the $x$ coordinate is twice the $y$ coordinate.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. If something looks suspiciously like a homework question you are encouraged to show any attempts you have made at solving the problem. Also to try and learn to do typesetting of the math to make it easier for others to read.

Comment: OK working on it

Comment: Ok all done help now

Comment: The derivate is $2x-4$. Hence, the function is strictly increasing for $x\ge 2$. We also have $f(3)=-6$. If $x_2$ is the positive root of $f(x)$, the desired open interval is $(3,x_2)$

Comment: Hint for the last question : The desired point is on the line $y=\frac{x}{2}$

Comment: The second question is almost answered below.

Comment: Help me figure it out please                                                                                               https://www.desmos.com/calculator/sfxxgenmpz

Answer (score 2):

OK starting to find the $\sqrt{7}$ using the graph we find that the roots of the graph are -0.6 and +4.6

I Think we should use the quadratic formula here to derive $\sqrt{7}$

$x=\dfrac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$

so we have

$x^2-4x-3=0\implies x=\dfrac{4\pm\sqrt{28}}{2}$

From there?

Comment: So $\frac{4 \pm \sqrt{28}}{2} = \frac{4 \pm \sqrt{4 \cdot 7}}{2} = \frac{4 \pm 2 \sqrt{7}}{2}$, which equals $2 \pm \sqrt{7}$.  So one root is $2 + \sqrt{7}$ and the other root is $2 - \sqrt{7}$.

Answer (score 2):

**For 3):**

So, to figure out which interval the function is *increasing* on, you need to trace the function drawn with a pencil (or look with your eyes).

When you trace the function **from left to right**, when your hand goes up, the intervals below on the $x$-axis are the intervals where the function is increasing.

As you trace the function from left to right, when your hand moves down, the intervals where your hand goes down are the intervals where the function is decreasing.

It should be clear from the above explanation that the interval on the $x$-axis where the function is *decreasing* is $[-1,2]$ and the interval on the $x$-axis where it is increasing is $[2,5]$.

**For 4):**

You correctly found in your answer that the roots are $2 + \sqrt{7}$ and $2 - \sqrt{7}$ using the quadratic formula.  Now, you also said by guessing that one root is 4.6 and one is -0.6

Since $2 + \sqrt{7}$ is positive (since the expression is adding two positive numbers), it must be the $4.6$ root, so $2 + \sqrt{7} = 4.6$ roughly.  That means $\sqrt{7} = 2.6$ roughly.

**For 5):**
It looks like it was answered in the comments.